# What are some good java libraries to search and scrape data out of a web page.

Tags: java, web-crawler, web-scraping, jsoup, webharvest

What are some good open source java libraries to search and scrape data out of a web page and stick it into a database.  For example, suppose I had a page such as:

```
<tr><td><b>Address:</b></td>
<td colspan=3>123 My Street        </td></tr>
```

"Address:" is the key, but I'm actually trying to get "123 My Street" which has a bunch of html tags and spaces in between.  Ideally I want to get the value between the td that follows the string "Address:".  It seems like JSoup can do the find, but I didn't see a good example on how to do the offset (I may have missed it).  Is there a library that handles key/value?

I'd also be interested in learning about any open source (MIT/Apache) initiatives for UI scripting similar to the Kapow Extraction Browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Web-Harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/).
It's open-source crawler written in Java.
It can be used as Java library, as command-line application or with it's standalone IDE.

You can use [`<xpath>`](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php#xpath) element to extract any value from the XHTML document.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good list of open source parsers: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

I've used [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) with great success for parsing tens of thousands of web pages in the wild. As for the "key-value" relationship, that's something you'll have to deal with yourself.